# Error 'Unimplemented handling of missing static target' whenever I try to show the bottom popup sheet using a flat button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The code is simple I have a container on which I have stacked different widgets and two of them are a search bar and a flat button, the flat button is used to raise the bottom sheet and make the search bar invisible whenever the bottom sheet is raised. The search bar is placed below the flat button. But whenever I press the flat button an exception is raised. I tried flutter and reloaded the app again but it was of no use.

Below is the error log:

```
The following _CompileTimeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Unimplemented handling of missing static target

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:706:14)
#1      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:789:36)
#2      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
#3      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:486:11)
#4      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:264:5)
...
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#3c005
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: possible
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(196.6, 163.0)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(40.8, 28.0)
  button: 1
  sent tap down
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (2) Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Unimplemented handling of missing static target
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was arising because my bottom sheet code(UI code) was on other dart file and once I pasted all the code to the `main.dart` file, everything worked as expected.

The Correct way to import a dart file is for using it in your main.dart file is as a package and the above error will not occur.
`import'package:project_name/path_(if inside a folder inside lib)/your_filename.dart';`